# Elasticsearch should operation query

Tags: elasticsearch

How can I imply a "should" operation for 
("tag"="A" OR "tag"="B") and "name"="cat"

like ?

```
 BoolQueryBuilder queryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
.should(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("tag","A"))
.shold(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("tag","B"))
```

.must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("name","cat"));

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do `("tag"="A" OR "tag"="B") and "name"="cat"`, you can do as follow :

```
 BoolQueryBuilder aOrB = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
.should(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("tag","A"))
.should(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("tag","B"))

 BoolQueryBuilder queryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
.must(aOrB);
.must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("name","cat"));
```